# Pasar un valor a un campo

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, djangorestframework, html-select

Estos son mis models

```
class Colegio(models.Model):
    id_colegio = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre_colegio = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre_colegio

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Colegios"
        verbose_name = "Colegio"
        ordering = ['nombre_colegio']

class Destino(models.Model):
    id_destino = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre_destino = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre_destino

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Destinos"
        verbose_name = "Destino"
        ordering = ['nombre_destino']

    class Tiempo(models.Model):
        id_tiempo = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        nombre_tiempo = models.CharField(max_length=50)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.nombre_tiempo

        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = "Tiempos"
            verbose_name = "Tiempo"
            ordering = ['nombre_tiempo']

    class Costo(models.Model):
        id_costo = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        nombre_colegio = models.ForeignKey(Colegio)
        nombre_destino = models.ForeignKey(Destino)
        nombre_tiempo = models.ForeignKey(Tiempo)
        valor = models.CharField(max_length=10)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.valor

        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = "Costos"
            verbose_name = "Costo"
```

Aqui esta mi template donde en un boton de seleccion multiple. Los datos son traidos desde la base de datos.

```
<form method="post" id="signin-form_id">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <select name=eleccion1 class="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                    <option>Seleccione el Colegio</option>
                    {% for colegio in colegios %}
                    <option><p>{{colegio.nombre_colegio}}</p></option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select name=eleccion2 class="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                <option selected destino="">Seleccione el Destino</option>
                {% for destino in destinos %}
                <option><p>{{destino.nombre_destino}}</p></option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select name=eleccion3 class="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                <option selected tiempo="">Seleccione el Tiempo</option>
                {% for tiempo in tiempos %}
                <option><p>{{tiempo.nombre_tiempo}}</p></option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" name="tarifa">
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <input type="submit" value="Costo" class="btn btn-success btn-rounded">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Acá esta mi `view` donde llamo los colegios, destinos, tiempos

```
class Cont(View):
    login_url = '/'
    template_name = 'listar_contratos.html'

    def get(self, request):
        listaColegios = Colegio.objects.all()
        listaDestinos = Destino.objects.all()
        listaTiempos = Tiempo.objects.all()

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'colegios': listaColegios, 'destinos': listaDestinos, 'tiempos': listaTiempos})
```

Lo que quiero es que al campo que es de tipo `text` se retorne el valor que se encuentra en los models (Costo). En la tabla de **Costo** están los costos de cada colegio con cada destino y tiempo.

Comment: Hola. Pues lo que tienes que implementar es el método `post` y usar esos valores para hacer un query en la tabla `Costo`.

Comment: y como podria hacer el query @César

Comment: algo así como costos_por_colegio = Costo.objects.filter(nombre_colegio=colegio), esto te devolverá un querySet con los costos de un determinado colegio.

Comment: Yo tengo el ajax pero no me manda el vaalor no se que error tengo. Me puedes ayudar @Borjinha10

Comment: Ya realice el ajax pero  no se que error tengo porque no me retorna el Costo @César